# Idiom gone wrong

Tags: meaning, grammar, idioms

In English there's the term "dream on" , the on here gives the idea of continuing , if I wanted to use on with pass would it mean passing exams continuously? or it just simply means passing out?
what is the meaning of pass on ?

Comment: Sometimes "passing on" is used as a euphemism referring to death.